# how to search using a textfield? php

Tags: php

I want to search a whole news feed by inserting a word in my text field. I have no idea how to do this. Here is my code, so you know what I mean with it.

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
    <tr><th>search: </th><td><input type="text" name="search" value="{$word}"></td></tr>
</form>
```

How can I check if the word I inserted in the searchbar, exists somewhere in the news feed?

My news feed is used like this:

```
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("newsfeed.xml");
    foreach($xml->channel->item as $item) {
        echo '<h1 class="title">' . $item->title . '</h1>';
        echo '<p class="desc">'.$item->description."</p>";
}
```

Comment: It really depends on what kind of results you want. Unfortunately there's not a way in PHP (or other languages) to attain the level of relevance that Google and Bing get in one or two lines. I'd advise reading up on different search techniques like wildcards, full-text search, indexing, root-word analyzing, etc etc and choosing the one that fits your needs.

Comment: A really simple but bold approach can be to look with [stristr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) if the $_POST['search'] is in either the $item->title or $item->description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the function [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

> Find the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle in the
>   haystack string.

Example:

```
$a = 'Long text to look into it.'

if (strpos($a, 'it') !== false)
    echo 'true';
```

In your case, you can use strpos either to find the word in the item title or the item description:

```
$a = $_GET['search'];

foreach($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    print_result = 0;  // flag to know if the search is in the feed.

    if (strpos($item->description, $a) !== false){
        print_result = 1;
    } // end if desc

    if (strpos($item->title, $a) !== false){
        print_result = 1;
    } // end if title


    if(print_result == 1){
        echo '<h1 class="title">' . $item->title . '</h1>';
        echo '<p class="desc">'.$item->description."</p>";
    } //end if print results.
} // end foreach
```

Comment: If you search for `Bus` won't this highlight Business?

Comment: @Mike you are right! it would show the results for all the matches of characters containing 'bus'. If you want only 'Bus', you'll need to do some more checks..

Comment: Note that `strpos` is case-sensitive. If you want to sanitaze user-inputs.. you can use `stripos`, wich is case-insensitive.. or use `strtolower` in the user-input and feed items to match your words...

Comment: as pointed by @MikeB, you can use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to search by word; you'll need to build regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a foreach like you do it now:
And make kind of relevance points for each news item. Something like if it's in the title then it's more relevant and if it's at the beginning and so on.
Then you can write it into an array and sort it.
I hope you have something like an id in your newsfeed.xml for this.